# Different video players for the Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360

I have been putting videos on my external hard drive and watching them on my xbox, and before you say anything, I'm not interested in streaming solutions, this is working out great.

However, Windows being the way they are, formats like `.mkv` aren't supported. I'd love to just circumnavigate their video player entirely.

Can I install a different, more friendly, media player?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to install video players on a 360 without modding your console. However, the Xbox One should have little difficulties thanks to Universal Windows Apps; the Metro VLC app comes to mind.

Comment: @Nolonar I wouldn't say 'little difficulty'. THere is no app to play mkv files be default on Xbox One. Though with October's update, mkv support will be introduced to the Media Player Preview app that only just got rolled out this month.

Comment: The October update looks like it'll be quite nice for external media